# Not sure if I'm answering the wrong question or wrongly answering the right question. Need suggestions please

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, prediction, supervised-learning

Thank you for taking the time to read my post.

I'm in a bit of a limbo here and really need some intervention. I have been working on an individual project. It is a supervised learning regression problem. After cleaning, initial analysis, EDA, and feature selection, the chosen dataset now has a total of 8 attributes and 7 of them are numerical. There are around 1000 observations of top global companies ranked as per the highest revenues. The attributes are as follow:

1. Names
2. Revenues 2022
3. Rev_Percentage_Change
4. Profits 2022
5. Pro_Percentage_Change
6. Assets
7. Market_Value
8. Employees

I made the first blunder when finalizing the research/problem question. Though I still think the question is pretty good but now I feel it cannot be answered with this dataset. The question is, "Predict profit 2023 for the global 1000 companies and rank them as per highest profit earned". The main idea behind this is that the profit is a better measure then revenue, and therefore companies should be ranked according to the most profit made for the year. As anyone would understand that the Revenue is money earned; and profit is the money saved.

So, to answer this question I did my research on google scholar to find similar works but could not find any material on the subject matter. Out of all the materials I could find, I shortlisted 10 research papers where there was some sort of prediction involved. Still, I could not find anything on exactly what I was doing. Except something that I realize now that most of the search results were projects on time series analysis. I did explore time series but it was like I was blindfolded or something and I did not realize that the question I'm trying to answer is basically a time series problem, and it can easily be solved given the right dataset. For example if we were to predict the profit of these 1000 companies and we had the dataset which contained profits for the last 10 years then we would've been in business! But as the data we have is profit for the year, even though I was able to generate the profit figures of last year with the help of "Profit_Percentage_Change" column. But I still felt that it cannot get the job done.

At this point I just went with the flow and wanted to apply the regression models to get somewhere at least. Therefore I applied four regression models, Multiple Linear regression, Random Forest Regressor, Decision Tree Regressor, and Support Vector Machine regressor. These models were applied properly with a 70/30 split, generated the predicted values, evaluated the models with RMSE, MSE, R Squared scores, and also with Cross validation (5fold) with Random Forest regressor outperforming the other three.

Even though I predicted the values, even compared the actual and the predicted but of course they were for present year. Something I gained from this exercise was to find out which one of these models performed the best. But it still did not answer my question, in fact I was no way near it. I could've predicted the profit for next year with the help of time series and appropriate dataset, but I was late for it.

I still tried to find the appropriate dataset but had no luck so the only choice I am left with now is to change my research question. I have thought it through but I am not able to come up with the right question. The only possible question I can think of is "which supervised machine learning model best performs in predicting the profit of global 1000 companies". But why am I doing this? What problem does it solve? Is it a good solid question you think? I'm doubtful.

Guys, I know that Stack overflow is not a personal coding service and nor it should be. All I'm asking is some sort of direction so that I can row the boat and get to the right destination. Any help from you would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for taking the time to read and respond to this.

Included all the details in the first section. Thank you

Comment: i would prefer to use  [LSTM (Long short term memory)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_short-term_memory) to predict the profit of the companies, because LSTM is suitable for processing and predicting important events with very long intervals and delays in time series.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. Do you think applying LSTM is a good idea given the variable we want to predict is profit for the next year and the available data is profit for this year. With just one column (Profit column of 1000 companies) and there is no trend etc, do you still think that an LSTM can be applied?

Comment: LSTMs are more suitable for long series, or series with variable lengths, if he struggles to find the data I think it will be only an unnecessary complication. but if you can find enough data and you have the will to set up a more complex code it's the best choice.

Comment: Yes, this makes sense. 
I don't think I can gather more data on this. If I did, it would either be unreliable or would take a lot of time and effort. That's what I felt recently, this question cannot be answered with this dataset. I might have to change the question at this point to make some sense of this.

Answer (score 1):

If I get what you have done in your experiments, you are passing to the regression models all the data except the profit which is the output that you're trying to predict, but you get the current year's profit and not the future one, as expected due to the dataset structure.

For doing what you want, predict the next year's profit, you need a time series with the "history" of that data, so each company should have these data for each year from the start, even the data of only 2021 and 2022 could do the job, anyway I don't think you can trust the results with such a short series.

If you can create such a dataset you can predict the full record so Revenues, profits, etc.. of one year, passing one or two or more records of the past years to the model.

For such type of application, I would do that with a neural network, a simple mlp with a few layers should give you good results but you need more data...

A base structure could be a model that takes all the data that you have in one record for one company for 3 years and return one record for the next year, or you can return only one value, the profit if you only need that.

For the last question, I don't know if it's worth predicting the revenue of one year by the other values of the same year, it's not my field, but I guess that it's a much easier task.

Here is an article where you can find some info on how to set up a simple neural network for time series predictions: [time series prediction with keras](https://machinelearningmastery.com/exploratory-configuration-multilayer-perceptron-network-time-series-forecasting/)

Hope this helped, good luck with your project.

Comment: Thank you very much for such a detailed reply. Much appreciated. For now, given the time constraint, I believe my best option is to change the research question and align it with the rest of the project to make some sense of it. The idea of generating more data and then using LSTM isn't bad, in fact I find it very interesting and probably will consider it but for another time. Thank you once again for you input.